# How can I run Single Razor Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor

Hi I want to make project that contains one Razor Class Lybrary.I want to use them like dll or other (I still don't now) in another Blazor WASM project.The problem is how to run and preview this Razor Component in developing process before I put it in Blazor project.How I know it is impossible to make this or I make wrong.I read a lot of examples but they are all for the case when all Razor components leaves inside blazor project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is imposible with case that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create other project like "MyDllDebug" and reference real project. When you finish your testing - make your library and "Debug" don't build in the package.